# Extract key from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Need to extract a key string (within an multidimensional array) and store in a variable.

```
<?php

$data = [
  ["Toyota" => [1,2,3]],
];

print_r($data);

$extracted_key = $data[0][0];
echo $extracted_key;
```

**Expected result:**

```
Toyota
```

Comment: Check this [array-keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: `print_r(array_keys($data[0])[0]);` Only heaven only knows what that is going to achieve for you

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please add this as answer and I will approve it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is just a tiny example, but it solve a problem of bigger cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `array_keys()` will dig that out for you

```
print_r(array_keys($data[0])[0]);
```

Not sure how useful this will be in the long run though

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any number of arrays on level 2

```
$data = [
  ["Toyota" => [1,2,3]],
];

foreach($data as $key=>$arr){
    $keys = array_keys($data[$key]);
    foreach($keys as $val){
        echo "$val\r\n";
    }

}
```